# How to display data from database into line graph using php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, charts, chart.js, linechart

I want to display monthly revenues from a database on a line graph. Currently there are two rows in the database.
First month: 250,000.
Second month: 268600.
**My problem is that the data is not displayed on the graph as expected**. The month values are below each other and there is only one of the revenue values(250000). But on the graph the value 268600 is plotted. Image of the graph:[image of the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iKlE.png)
Database image:[database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJAhG.png)

**How can I display the data correctly on the graph?** So 1 month : 250000. 2 months : 268600.
**I use chart.js for the chart.**

Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('connection.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">   
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/statistics.css">
    <title>statistics</title>
</head>

<body>
   

            <?php
            session_start();
            require_once('connection.php');
            ?>

            <?php
            $id = $_SESSION['id'];
            $sql = "SELECT month, revenue FROM revenue_per_month WHERE user_id = $id";

            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                    $revenue = $row["revenue"];
                    $month = $row["month"];
                }
            }

            $revenue_value = array();
            $month_value = array();
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                $revenue_value[] = $row["revenue"];
                $month_value[] = $row["month"];
            }


            ?>


            <div class="diagram_div">
                <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
            </div>
            <!--todo=============== script ===============-->

            <script>
                const data = {
                    labels: [<?php echo json_encode($month_value) ?>],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Revenue value:',
                        backgroundColor: '#20e0307a',
                        borderColor: '#04aa1a',
                        data: [<?php echo json_encode($revenue_value) ?>],
                        borderWidth: 1,
                    }]
                };

                var chartEl = document.getElementById("myChart");
                chartEl.height = 250;
                const config = {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: data,
                    options: {
                        plugins: {

                            title: {
                                display: true,
                                text: 'Revenues'
                            },
                            legend: {
                                display: true,
                                position: 'bottom'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
            </script>
           

 <script>
                const myChart = new Chart(
                    document.getElementById('myChart'),
                    config
                );
            </script>


  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want a single dataset, you need a single array (not two). So change to :

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $revenue_value[] = [
        'x' => $row["month"],
        'y' => $row["revenue"]
    ];
}
```

Then in your javascript 'data' variable, remove the square brackets :

```
            const data = {
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Revenue value:',
                    backgroundColor: '#20e0307a',
                    borderColor: '#04aa1a',
                    data: <?= json_encode($revenue_value) ?>,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                }]
            };
```